# store binary of decimal in char array

Tags: c, arrays, binary, bit-shift

I want to store binary equivalent of decimal number in `char` array by applying below code, but the problem is I am not able to hold the last bit of the decimal number. I am getting garbage values.

```
 int k,j;
 char c[40];
 j=32;
 scanf("%d",&k);

 while(k)
 {    
     k=k>>1;
     c[j]=k|1;
     j--;
 }

 puts("number is");
 puts(c);
```

Comment: Right shift of a negative value is _implementation defined_, thus might yield something unexpected.

Comment: @Olaf Can you name an architecture, where right-shifting a negative value by 1 will produce something unexpected?

Comment: You should pass to function `puts` a null-terminated array of characters, not just any array of characters. This function prints all the characters up until the first occurrence of a null character. In your example, such character appears as soon as you have a binary digit which is equal to 0. If no such digit exists (i.e., in the case of `k == 0xFFFFFFFF`), then your program yields undefined behavior. In any case, it is not printing the binary representation of the input number, because you are setting the characters in the array to `0` and `1`, not to `'0'` and `'1'`.

Comment: @hyde: There are various CPUs which only provide logical (unsiggned) right shift. For these, the compilers most likely (and will) do not preserve the sign. Note: it is not mine to point you to a specific architecture, but your's to proof it will never happen, as the standard actually allows. I'd rather rely on the (also IDB) of casting `int` to `unsigned`, as _that_ is nuch more unlikely to fail. Note: if you do _expect_ the value to change sign, that would rather not be "unexpected".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the problems noted by @SouravGhosh, you need to

(5) convert from the digits 0/1 to the character values for `'0'` and `'1'` by adding in the value of the character `'0'` [actually Sourav noted that too], and

(6) pick off the low-order bit *before* shifting `k` right by 1 bit.

Here's a working version:

```
char c[40];
int j=39;
c[j--]='\0';
while(k)
    {
    c[j]=(k&1)+'0';
    j--;
    k=k>>1;
    }

puts("number is ");
puts(&c[j+1]);
```

Comment: Is your point (5) is my point (3) second part or am I missing something? :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh No, I missed that, sorry.  (Fixed.)

Comment: @SouravGhosh  i'm a beginner , sorry to ask
why char '0' is used

Comment: @madara Never be sorry while asking for information, it's good that you asked. To represent the digit `1` as `char`, we need the ASCII value, and all the ASCII values of integer literal are starting `48` (which is `'0'`) onwards. Please see [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) table.

Comment: in     'puts(&c[j+1])'  is  '&'  used because array is used with its size
normally i see     'puts(c)'

Comment: The loop we have constructed here is slightly unusual in that it fills in the array c[] from right to left, not left to right.  And we always decrement j (`j--`) after filling in a character.  So at the end, j "points" to an unused cell in the array one to the left of where our string begins. j is the index of that cell, `&c[j]` would be a pointer to that cell, `j+1` is the cell where we want to begin printing, and `&c[j+1]` is a pointer to the cell where we want to begin printing.  `puts()` wants a pointer.

Comment: Equivalently, we could use `puts(c+j+1)`, although to my mind that makes it even less clear what's going on.

Comment: With respect to the adding '0' part: it's easier to understand at first if you were to write `c[j] = (k&1) + 48`.  But once you know that you have to do this, and as long as you know how character values work in C, it's much, **much** better to write `c[j] = (k&1) + '0'`, because that way you never have to waste time going to asciitable.com to look up the actual values, and as a side benefit your code is portable to any machines that don't use ASCII (not that there are too many of those any more).

Comment: Consider `k==0`, nothing is printed out.  Use `do { ...} while (k)`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the lexicographical representation for the binary.

You need to take care of few things.

1. You *must* initialize `k` before using. Ask for user input (or "hardcode", as *we* say) the value for `k`.
2. If you want to use array `c` as *string*, you need to null-terminate it.
3. You need to perform `&` with a value of `1` to take out the last bit. Add that with `'0'` (Remember, *lexicographical*). Store that.
4. Current array indexing will put you into trouble. You can use normal array indexing with `j`, starting from `0`. After the loop, you need to null-terminate the last index and then go for printing.

A pseudo-code will look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int val = 16;
    char  bin [128] = {0};
    int index = 0;

    while(val)
    {
        bin[index] = '0' + (val&1u);
        val = val >> 1;
        index++;
    }
    bin[index] = 0;

    puts(bin);


    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[SEE A LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/khI60R)</kbd>

---

<sup>NOTE: You *may* want to reverse the string before printing it.</sup>

Comment: need to initialize `k` too.

Comment: Hello Sourav, Sir. May I suggest you add the code (or whatever the link presents) to your answer? Your answer might become useless if ideone decides to change anything.

Comment: @Olaf Hello Sir, how do you do? Actually I did not want to _spoonfeed_ the code. Do you recommend adding the code here?

Comment: Fine, tanks, hope you are well, too. About the link: I mostly refer to the corresponding [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please note, I do not suggest to remove the link as such; it's just what if the link is offline? You're making the value of your answer depending on an external site. However, it is just a friendly suggestion. Fine for me if you do not follow it.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for the suggestion, always welcome. I have added the code here itself, If OP is clicking the link, (s)he will get to see the code _anyway_. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If interested, here is a slightly different method...

Consider that for a graphical binary representation of a 32 bit integer, you would need to contain 33 bytes:  32 for 1s and 0s, and 1 for string NULL terminator.  As you walk through any 32 bit representation of an integer value, you can logical and (`&`) the corresponding bit of 2^32 (2147483648) with each bit position of your input integer value to determine if that position should be a "1" or a "0", stacking the resultant character (***[ASCII](http://www.imagekb.com/ascii-table)***) representations of `1` or `0` (48 or 49) as you go, into a string.

Here is the example to convert an integer into a 32 bit binary representation...

```
const char *byte_to_binary32(long x)
{
    static char b[33]; // bits plus '\0'
    b[0] = '\0';
    char *p = b;  
    //unsigned long long z; required only if 64 bit conversion
    unsigned long z;//this is sufficient for 32 bit conversion
    for (z = 2147483648; z > 0; z >>= 1)       //2^32
    {
        *p++ = (x & z) ? '1' : '0';
    }
    return b;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Binary: %s\n\n", byte_to_binary32(100));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some detail should you care:  better to use `unsigned long z` rather than `unsigned int z` as `int/unsigned` need only be 16-bit - still common in embedded world in 2015.  Further, it matches your use of `long` in `byte_to_binary32(long x)`.

Comment: @Chux - Good point.  Since this is really a rarely used parlor trick, I wonder how often it would be implemented in any embedded system.  But point taken, edit made.  Thanks again.